# Excel-VBA : Run-Time error in Referring and modifying axes scale in Excel Charts

Tags: excel, vba

I am having two charts in an excel sheet ("DesiredData"), and my purpose is to determine the chart having a greater value of Maximum Scale on Y-axis and then changing the value of Maximum Scale in the other chart. My code is :

```
Sub reArrange()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DesiredData")
    Dim maxScale1 As Long
    Dim maxScale2 As Long
    .ChartObjects(1).Activate
    'runtime error at this line
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).Activate
    maxScale1 = .ChartObjects(1).Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
    .ChartObjects(2).Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).Activate
    maxScale2 = .ChartObjects(2).Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale
    If maxScale1 > maxScale2 Then
        .ChartObjects(2).Activate
        .ChartObjects(2).Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = maxScale1
    Else
        .ChartObjects(1).Activate
        .ChartObjects(1).Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = maxScale2
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

It is giving Run-Time error the specified line, please help me out.

Comment: look at using the objects, so dim axYAxis1 and axYAxis2, then intellisense in VBA will show you the properties you can access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
Dim c As ChartObject
Dim c2 As ChartObject
Dim a1 As Axis
Dim a2 As Axis

Set c = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)

Set c2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(2)

Dim x As Chart

Set x = c.Chart

Set a1 = x.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, xlPrimary)

Set x = c2.Chart

Set a2 = x.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, xlPrimary)

a1.MaximumScale = a2.MaximumScale
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works, if you remove some unnecessary `.Activate` commands. First of all, you can't activate an axis, only select it. Second of all, there's no need to select an axis or activate a chart to do what you want. You do need to insert `.Chart` between `.ChartObjects(i)` and `.Axes(xlValue)`.

The following ought to work as expected:

```
Sub reArrange()
  Dim maxScale1 As Long
  Dim maxScale2 As Long
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DesiredData")
    maxScale1 = .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
    maxScale2 = .ChartObjects(2).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale
    If maxScale1 > maxScale2 Then
      .ChartObjects(2).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = maxScale1
    Else
      .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = maxScale2
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```